# Creating logic for a searchbar

Tags: javascript, html, searchbar

I'm trying to create logic for my search bar to search through elements by their IDs, but it's not working. As can be seen in the HTML code, the elements contain pictures. That's why I'm using this method to display the elements.

here is the HTML code:

```
<html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>BONIXS</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="BONIXS.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Ghost Runner.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <a href="D:/VSCODE/STEAM.html" id="Start">BONIXS</a>
    </div>
    <div> 
    <img src="Ghosrunner.png" alt="Ghost Runner" id="Ghostrunner">
    </div>
    <div class="Download">
    <a href="Ghost Runner.zip" download>
        <button class="Download-button">Download</button>
    </a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the JavaScript logic code for it:

```
const searchBar = document.getElementById('searchBar');
const searchResults = document.getElementById('searchResults');

searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  console.log('Keyup event detected'); // Check if event listener is triggered

  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    const searchTerm = searchBar.value.toLowerCase();
    console.log('Search term:', searchTerm); // Check the search term

    searchResults.innerHTML = '';

    const matchingResults = performSearch(searchTerm);
    console.log('Matching results:', matchingResults); // Check the matching results

    displayResults(matchingResults);
  }
});

function performSearch(searchTerm) {
  const allElements = document.querySelectorAll('[id]');
  return Array.from(allElements).filter(element => element.id.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm));
}

function displayResults(results) {
  results.forEach(result => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = result.id;
    searchResults.appendChild(li);
  });
}
```

I tried multiple times but it didn't work

Comment: Have you checked your browser's developer tools, to check for any errors reported in the console? Do you have any elements with an `id` attribute?

Comment: The whole HT.ML cod is now visible

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working as expected. There are no IDs elements in your HTML. Try to type for example "Ukraine" and you'll see matching results.

```js
const searchBar = document.getElementById('searchBar');
const searchResults = document.getElementById('searchResults');

searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  console.log('Keyup event detected'); // Check if event listener is triggered

  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    const searchTerm = searchBar.value.toLowerCase();
    console.log('Search term:', searchTerm); // Check the search term

    searchResults.innerHTML = '';

    const matchingResults = performSearch(searchTerm);
    console.log('Matching results:', matchingResults); // Check the matching results

    displayResults(matchingResults);
  }
});

function performSearch(searchTerm) {
  const allElements = document.querySelectorAll('[id]');
  return Array.from(allElements).filter(element => element.id.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm));
}

function displayResults(results) {
  results.forEach(result => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = result.id;
    searchResults.appendChild(li);
  });
}
```

```html
<ul style="display: none;">
    <li id="Ukraine">Ukraine</li>
    <li id="United States">United States</li>
    <li id="Japan">Japan</li>
</ul>
<input type="text" id="searchBar" placeholder="Search...">
<ul id="searchResults"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the input in a form to get "Enter" functionality.

**Note:** Tyr typing "or" andpressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```js
const searchForm = document.getElementById('search-form');
const searchResults = document.getElementById('search-results');

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const searchTerm = e.target.elements.term.value.toLowerCase();
  console.log('Search term:', searchTerm); // Check the search term
  searchResults.innerHTML = ''; // Clear existing results
  const matchingResults = performSearch(searchTerm);
  console.log('Matching results:', matchingResults); // Check the matching results
  displayResults(matchingResults);
};

const performSearch = (searchTerm) =>
  [...document.querySelectorAll('[id]')]
    .filter(element => element.id.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm));

const displayResults = (results) => {
  searchResults.innerHTML = '';
  results.forEach(result => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = result.id;
    searchResults.appendChild(li);
  });
};

searchForm.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);
```

```css
body { padding: 0.25rem; }
h2 { margin: 0; }
ul { padding: 0.5rem 0 0 1.25rem; margin: 0; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form id="search-form" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="search" id="search-term" name="term" placeholder="Search...">
</form>
<hr />
<h2>Examples</h2>
  <span id="apple">Apple</span>,
  <span id="ape">Ape</span>,
  <span id="orange">Orange</span>,
  <span id="orangutan">Orangutan</span>
<hr />
<h2>Results</h2>
<ul id="search-results"></ul>
```