# Creating logic for a searchbar( that searches thorugh elments ids)

Tags: javascript, html, searchbar

I'm trying to create logic for my search bar to search through elements by their IDs, but it's not working. As can be seen in the HTML code, the elements contain pictures. That's why I'm using this method to display the elements.

here is the HTML code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>BONIXS</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="BONIXS.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="STEAM.CSS">
    <script src="STEAM.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1 id="Start">BONIXS</h1>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <input type="text" id="searchBar" placeholder="Search">
    <ul id="searchResults"></ul>
    <br><br><br><br>
    <div>
        <h2 id="Action">ACTION</h2>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <a href="Action/Ghostrunner/Ghost Runner.html"><img src="Action/Ghostrunner/Ghostrunner.jpg" alt="Ghost Runner" class="Games" id="Ghostrunner"></a>
        <a href="Action/Atomic Heart/Atomic Heart.html"><img src="Action/Atomic Heart/Atomic Heart.jpg" alt="Atomic Heart" class="Games" id="Atomic-Heart"></a>
        <a href="Action/High On Life/High On Life.html"><img src="Action/High On Life/High On Life.jfif" alt="High On Life" class="Games" id="High-On-Life"></a>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the JavaScript logic code for it:

```
const searchBar = document.getElementById('searchBar');
const searchResults = document.getElementById('searchResults');

searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  console.log('Keyup event detected'); // Check if event listener is triggered

  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    const searchTerm = searchBar.value.toLowerCase();
    console.log('Search term:', searchTerm); // Check the search term

    searchResults.innerHTML = '';

    const matchingResults = performSearch(searchTerm);
    console.log('Matching results:', matchingResults); // Check the matching results

    displayResults(matchingResults);
  }
});

function performSearch(searchTerm) {
  const allElements = document.querySelectorAll('[id]');
  return Array.from(allElements).filter(element => element.id.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm));
}

function displayResults(results) {
  results.forEach(result => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = result.id;
    searchResults.appendChild(li);
  });
}
```

I tried multiple times but it didn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating logic for a searchbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76291161/creating-logic-for-a-searchbar)

Comment: You have a bunch of console.logs.  What feedback are you getting from those lines?  It would be helpful if we could run your code, but crucial parts of the html are missing like searchbar.

Comment: hey, i edited the question and added the whole html code, now you run the code